# Datasource Subitems Items not being published in Sitecore 7.2

Tags: publishing

I am working on a Sitecore 7.2 instance, and I have noticed some peculiar behaviour.

I have a large collection of pages and datasources. When I create a folder to contain a certain type of datasource, and then create a datasource with subitems, and then do a publish, the subitems do not get published.

The folder and the parent item do get published however. There is no workflow involved. I have tried republish and smart publish

Comment: Wait, so this happens even when you republish the whole content tree?

Comment: There is already one question asked about publishing here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/754/item-being-skipped-during-publish

Perhaps you will find answer there.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko yes. When you go up to the "content" node and republish, it publishes everything except for the sub-items

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I dont think this is a duplicate of that question - this is a problem in the content editor, not the experience editor

Comment: @PhilBurton Have you looked at whether the items in question are publishable?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko yes - the items are publishable, and have no workflow attached

Comment: @PhilBurton have the sub items got a content version in the language you are publishing?

Comment: Silly question but are you logging in as admin? Do you see the publish subitems & related items checkbox when publishing? Some roles don't have those checkboxes by default.

Comment: I would check the web database first. Maybe they are there, only the templates are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all above points, check any of below points:

1. Have you checked the template of the sub-items is published or not? If template is not published, surely the items won't get published.
2. Check whether Sitecore adds these items in publishing queue or not. For that, you can enable publishing statistics inside  pipeline by doing below config change, and check logs what Sitecore does with these items - whether it adds to queue or not. Through these logs, you will be able to know the reason why items got skipped while publishing.

```xml
<processor type="Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.UpdateStatistics, Sitecore.Kernel" runIfAborted="true">
     <traceToLog>true</traceToLog>
</processor>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the `PublishEmptyItems` setting that was added in v7.2. By default that is set to false. What this means is if you have an item in your content tree that does not have an active version – even if there are children items under it and you have “Publish Subitems” selected, not only will it not publish that item, it will actually remove it and the children in your target database if it was previously there.

That part is apparently is by design. In previous versions, this wasn’t a choice and it would always publish empty items.

The actual bug is if you publish one or more empty items of a given language and no items actually get published, it will remove the respective language from /sitecore/System/Languages.

To work around it, turn the setting on:

```xml
<setting name="Publishing.PublishEmptyItems" value="true" />
```

src: [3 New Sitecore v7.2 Bugs You Need To Know About Before Go-Live](http://maxslabyak.com/sitecore/3-new-sitecore-v7-2-bugs-need-know-go-live/)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. The parent items of the sub items that are not being published does have a version, but no data in it's only field (although im pretty sure the template inherits from standard template, so therefore it has all the standard fields)

Comment: Actually, come to think about it, this doesn't make sense - the item parent is being published, it's just the subitems that arent, and the sub items aren't "empty"